# displaytag.properties in multiple projects

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, displaytag

I have several spring projects with displaytag 1.2 as dependency (ivy). Each project has its own displaytag.properties file placed under Java Resources -> resources folder. The problem is when I'm running it localy (Eclipse with Tomcat) it seems that only one displaytag.properties is shared among all other projects.

How can i specify that each project should load its own displaytag.properties?

This is the same problem when I'm deploying to a server. I've placed this property file under WEB-INF/classes, but again, only one property file is loaded and shared among other projects.

Comment: How do other projects know about that file? Something is wrong with your Eclipse setup.

Comment: I've read somewhere that in Eclipse context everything is "visible".  I've checked Java Build Path and the resources folder is there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, when there are several projects depending on same displaytag, that upon starting a server only one displaytag.properties is loaded. So, I've placed displaytag.properties in a jar of one project and for the second project I've used **display:setProperty** tag inside a jsp. Now everything works.